# How to model this context so its possible to create custom questions and collect answers?

Tags: php, database, laravel, database-design, eloquent

**Context:**

When a user (conference creator) creates a conference he can create a registration form for that conference. So he accesses the page "http://proj.test/conference/edit/1/questions" to edit the form to the conference with id 1.

In this page he can associate the existing questions to each registration type trough checkboxes. He can also click in "Add custom questions" to add more custom questions to the form.

For example, he can create a custom question "Whats your phone number?" and after can associate this question to the registration type "General" for example or to any other all registration types that he previously has created.

So, when the conference creator accesses "http://proj.test/conference/edit/1/questions/create" he has access to a form to create new custom questions for the conference with id 1.

In this form, the user (conference creator) needs to select the title for the question (Ex: Phone number) and the type of question (Ex: text) and then click on "Store Question".

The type of question field is a select menu with 5 options (text, long text, radio button, select menu and checkbox). 
If the user selects the type of question as a radio button, select menu or checkbox it appears some text inputs so the user can insert the values for each option.

[image]

Then in the front end when a user does a registration, for example the user John does a registration with 2 participants, him and Jake, in  the registration type "Rt 001", so he needs to fill a form, in this case, he needs to fill the fields for each participant since the conference creator selected the option "collect info from all participants". The registration form asks always for the name and email of the user that does the registration but in this case the registration form also asks the user for the "what is your phone number" because this field created by the conference creator was associated by the conference creator to the registration type the user is registering (Rt 001):

[image]

**Doubts:**

I'm with some doubts about how to organize this context in terms of tables, columns, and relationships to proper model this parts:

- the part of is possible to create custom questions and store if the field is mandatory or not
- the part of collect answers later when the user does the registration in the conference in one or more registration type(s) of the conference
- the part to be possible to the conference creator select can select to collect data from all participants or just for the user that does the registration

**// Conference Model**

```
class Conference extends Model
{

     // A conference has many registration types
     public function registrationTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\RegistrationType', 'conference_id');
     }
    // A conference can have  many questions
    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question', 'conference');
    }

     // A conference has one organizer
     public function organizer(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**RegistrationType model:**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }

    // A registration type has many questions
    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question', 'registration_type_id');
    }
}
```

**// Question Model**

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
    public function registration_type(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\RegistrationType');
    }

}
```

DB Diagram, it's incomplete and may be incorrect to model this context but shows the image diagram that I have for now: http://ibb.co/gVYVJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the information I got from questions and discussions, I have made schema changes. Note: in this schema, I am using naming standards used by laravel(by default). like plural table names, Primary keys will be 'id' etc.

[image]

Most of the part is similar to the schema in the question. I will explain it a bit,

- **users** - the table that holds conference creator.
- **conferences** - conferences, created_user_id is the user who created it.
- **registration_types** - holds registration types and conference_id link to conference it belongs to.
- **questions** - holds questions with conference_id shows which conference question belongs,
- **registration_types** pivot table to hold registration type to questions mapping.
- **registrations** - table that holds registration info.
- **participants** - holds entries for participants with name and email fields. each participant will have separate registration_type.
- **answers** - holds the answers given by each participant. it has question_id to indicate which question & participant_id to indicate which participant it belongs to.

The above schema adds `required` option for each registration types, so that you can make a question mandatory in one type and not mandatory in another. required field is added as an [extra attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to `registration_type_questions` pivot table.

Finding questions based on registration type

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Question::class, 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}

$registration_type->questions->withPivot('required');
```

Adding answer to question by a participant.

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    public function question(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Question::class);
    }
    public function participant(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Participant::class);
    }
}

Answer::create([
   'participant_id' => $participant_id,
   'question_id' => $question_id,
   'answer' => 'answer'
])
```

**Usage of `conference_id` in `questions` table**

`conference_id` hold the conference which question belongs. This will be useful to show already created questions in edit/create conference page.

**How to handle user registrations,**

`only_for_registration` flag is for 'Only from the user that holds registration' option given conference creation page.  If it is false means, you will not show name and email fields to extra participants.

**Example**

To make it more clear, Let me go through the example you have given.

1. Conference creator "Jake" create an account on the system.

   - We will create an entry in users table with necessary account fields.
2. "Jake" creates a new conference and selected "All Participants" option.

   - create a new entry in conference table with name and `only_for_registration` flag set to `false`(Because Jake chooses "All Participants").
3. "Jake" creates two registration type for "rt 1" and "rt 2".

   - create two entries in `registration_types` table with `conference_id`(from step 2) and name. "rt 1" with `id` 1 and "rt 2" with `id` 2.
4. "Jake" create a question "Whats your phone number?" with type text.

   - creates an entry in `questions` table with question text and "conference_id" as id from step2. Now, you can show questions in confrence edit page using `Questions::where("confrence_id", $current_confrence_id)->get()`. That is the usage of `confrence_id` in questions table.
5. "Jake" associate "Whats your phone number?" question only with "rt 2".

   - Adds entry in `registration_type_questions` with 'question_id' 1(from step 4) , `registration_type_id` 2 (from step 3 of "rt 2"). If "Jake" is selected question is mandatory you can set `required` flag as true.
6. In frontend "John" comes to the registration page and click on "Register".
7. "John" select 2 "rt 1" participants and 2 "rt 2" participants and click "Next".

   - Since we are coming from conference page, we already have `conference_id`, get all `registration_types` using `$conference->registrationTypes` oneToMany relation.
   - Once john press "Next" you can keep this information in session or in front-end itself. No need to commit to the database at this stage since user information is not provided.
8. "John" sees the form to fill 4 user entries, all having a name and email fields and 2 entries having extra "Whats your phone number?" question.

   - By default only show name and email only for first entry but since `only_for_registration` flag is false, show name and email fields for all entries.
   - For each entries get questions using `$registation_type->questions` relation. So since only 2 entries have "rt 2" we will only show "Whats your phone number?" to 2 fields and keep hidden `question_id` field.
   - Optionally, For all entries let the user switch between registration types he has selected. This way he has flexibility to choose the first participant, ie, himself to be rt2.
9. "John" filled answer to all questions and click "Next".

   - Create an entry in "registration" table.
   - Loop through all the entries in step8.

     - create an entry in participants table with registration_id from step8, registration_type value, and email and name. Keep email and name null when it is not required from additional users.
     - if the question is a custom question, create an entry in answers table with participant id from the last point and hidden question_id field.

If `only_for_registration` flag is true ie, "Jake" selected "Only from the user that does the registration", Then you can only show email and name fields only to the first entry.

Comment: Thanks, your schema also has this part of collect data from "only from the user that does the registration" or collect data from "all participants"? And a user can do registrations in a conference, so should be a relation between the user and conference and maybe between users and registrations also?

Comment: When a user that does a registration in a conference he can register multiple participants that can be or not registered in the system, but there is only 1 registration with multiple participants.  The guy that does the registration can be or not a participant of the conference.

Comment: And the "created_user_id" in the questions table can you explain why is necessary? I didn't understand. And, you said that the questions table " holds questions and custom questions". I don't understand which questions?  Maybe I didn't explain well. The questions are always custom questions. When a user does a registration he needs to select one or more registration types and then fill a registration form with the specific custom questions of the selected registration types. The registration form asks always the user that does the registration for his name and email and then the form also asks

Comment: ...for the fields that are associated to the registration types selected by the user that is doing the registration.

Comment: @JohnZ, i have addressed your concerns in the answer itself.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm not understanding well some points, maybe I didn't explain well. A user can create conferences but a user can also register in conferences, a user can do both things. So I'm not understanding why this field "only_for_registration" is necessary and also it is not necessary a 1 to many relationships between the user table and registration table. Maybe with a example of the process in the back end and front end is more clear:

Comment: In the backend: There is a conference creator, for example, "Jake" that created a specific conference for example "test conference". And after creating the conference this conference creator created two registration types "rt 1" and "rt 2". After creating the registration types the conference creator also created a custom question "Whats your phone number?". For the registration type, "rt 1" the conference creator didn't associate any custom questions. But for the registration type "rt 2" the conference creator associated  the custom question "Whats your phone number?"

Comment: In the frontend: Then, for example, the user John is on the conference details page of the conference "test conference" and click "Register". This conference has 2 registration types, "rt 1" and "rt2". And user John, for example, wants to register 4 participants, him and 3 colleagues. And for example, 2 colleagues want the registration type "rt 1" and John and other colleague want to register in the registration type "rt 2".

Comment: So When John clicks in "Register" in the conference details page it appears a form where John needs to select that he wants 2 tickets for the registration type "rt 1" and 2 for the registration type "rt 2" and then click on "Next".

Comment: Then it appears a form to collect the necessary info for the registration. In this case, first, it appears an area to collect the name and email of the guy that is doing the registration, so the user John needs to fill in his name and email. Then if the conference creator "Jake" has selected the option "collect info from all participants" it will appear 4 areas, each area to collect info of each participant. So John will need to fill in the name and email of each participant that are always mandatory fields independently of the registration type.

Comment: He needs also to fill in his phone number and the phone number of the college because he and that college wants the registration type "rt 2" that has that custom question. For the other two participants, John only needs to introduce the name and email.

Comment: If the conference creator "Jake" has selected the option "collect info just for the guy that does the registration" the user John needs only to fill in his name and email and also his phone number. The phone number is necessary because he is doing a registration that includes one or more participants that will be registered in the registration type "rt 2" that has the custom question "whats your phone number" associated. Then John clicks next and the registration is concluded.

Comment: Note: When a conference creator creates a conference that conference doesn't have any custom question by default. The only fields that will appear when a user does a registration are the name and email by default and name and email are not custom questions because area always necessary. The conference creator can create custom questions for a conference that he has created but that questions will not be shared with other conferences, are questions for that specific conference of that conference creator.

Comment: @JohnZ, i have updated the answer with few schema changes and example. Please have a look. also, There is no relation between user table and registrations table. Also since questions cannot be shared between confrences, I have updated `created_user_id` to `conference_id`. Also name and email moved to participants table.

Comment: Thanks really for your detailed answer. I just don't understand why there is no relation between user and registration. For example like that is not possible to know which user does the registration, for example in this example that John was the user that did the registration with 4 participants? And the participant's table when the conference creator selects to collect info "only from the user that does the registration" the name and email stay null after the user does the registration?

Comment: @JohnZ,  If conference creator selects "only from the user that does the registration" name and email of 3 participants will be null. As you have suggested if you will hold registered user info in users table you have to duplicate email and name fields in both users and participants table.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know if with that schema is possible to know which user did a specific registration? For example, the conference creator should also have access in the backend to a list of the users that did a registration in conferences that he has created.

Comment: @JohnZ, 'which user did a specific registration' is a property of registration, so you can add it to registrations table, as main_participant_id.

Comment: Thanks really!! But it's not more appropriate to have a relationship with users and registrations? For example when a user does the registration we can insert the id of the authenticated user, that is the user that is doing the registration, in the registration column "main_participant_id". But then since we dont have a relation between registration and user tables is possible to get the list of users that did registrations?

Comment: the registered user we will not add it to the user's table. it will be only in participant table, so no need for registrations-user mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need a pivot table to associate questions to multiple registration types (without copying them).

This table could be named `registration_type_question` and would have two columns:
`registration_type_id` (moved from `questions`), `question_id`

There is now a `BelongsToMany` relationship between `RegistrationType` and `Question`:

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'registration_type_question');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the models of the conference and question can stay as are in the question? Because a conference needs also to be related to the questions. And where to store the answer, can be in the question_registration_type migration? Like:  class CreateQuestionRegistrationTypeTable extends Migration{public function up() {Schema::create('question_registration_type', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->integer('question_id'); $table->integer('registration_type_id'); $table->string('answer');  $table->timestamps();});}}

Comment: Conferences and questions are still related via `questions.conference_id`. The table looks good, you only have to add a `user_id` column. And you could name it `answers` ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I dont understand why user_id is necessary? A user can create a conference and user table is related to the conference table but maybe is not necessary to be related with the "CreateQuestionRegistrationTypeTable".

Comment: The structure should not be correct in the create it is appearing always errors, now is appearing "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fields' in 'field list'".

Comment: By user I meant the conference attendee who answers the questions.

Comment: Where does the error occur? In `QuestionController::create()`? Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: Thanks. The user_id, the conference_id and the answers columns are in the Questions table or in question_registration_type table?

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread your first comment. The `question_registration_type` table only requires two columns: `question_id`, `registration_type_id`

Comment: For the answers you need a separate table: `attendee_id`, `question_id`, `registration_type_id `, `answer`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not understanding well how all structure in terms of tables and fields to be possible to create custom questions, associate the questions to the registration types so then when the user is registering in the conference and selects a specific registration type to register, fill in the form corresponding to the registration type that he is registering and store the answers that the user des. The name and email of the user are always necessary, then each registration type can have or not custom questions for the user that does the registration answer.

Comment: I made a diagram with the structure I have for now:http://ibb.co/gVYVJS.

Comment: When a user does a registration in the conference he can register only him but also other people in the same registration or even he can just register other people.

Comment: Can a participant choose one or multiple registration types? Your database structure says one, your question multiple.

Comment: Thanks. Can choose multiple registration types. For example the user John can do a registration with 2 participants him and Jake, and can register him in the registration type "rt 001" and Jake in the registration type "rt 002".

Comment: But only one per person?

Comment: One person do the registration but one person can register multiple participants, but there is only 1 registration with multiple participants. The guy that does the registration can be or not a participant, he can register only colleagues for example if some colleagues ask him to register them because they dont have account or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom question"?

Comment: When a user does a registration in a conference, for example when John does a registration in a conference he needs to always fill in the name and email independently of the registration type where he is registering. But the conference creator can create custom questions like "What is your phone number?" and associate that question to one or more registration types. For example if John is doing a registration in the registration type "rt 001" and the conference creator have created a custom question "Whats your phone number?" and associate that question to the registration type "rt 001".

Comment: Then, in the frontend, when the user John does a registration, he needs to select the registration type where he wants to register. If the registration type selected is "rt001" besides the name and email he need also to fill in the "Whats your phone number?" field.

Comment: The conference creator can also create registration types for the conference, like "general", "plus", anything. And obviously, he can only associate a custom question to a specific registration type when that registration type already was previously created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166638/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-johnz).